# Trigger Send APIs limitation on number of requests

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I am trying to send email through batch job from Salesforce.
Marketing Cloud Triggered Send API works for the first request.

Next requests get timeout. Although its not a best practice to call API recursively from code, is there a known limitation on Triggered Send APIs?

I tried with appx 50-100 calls with batch size 1.

Comment: not gonna answer as you specifically ask for the limits and I don't have them. Just a thought however: I am pretty sure that you can send a TS to multiple users at once instead of looping through batches of 1. Would that make no sense for you? Cause it might make the question obsolete.
I am referring to method: messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:<tsd_external_key>/send

Comment: To my knowledge there is no 'defined' limits on the API, just general best practices. Are you using SOAP or REST to make these calls? Is it a trigger send definition, a trigger Journey entry? A transactional message message? Is it Email or SMS? I assume each one of these has different capabilities. I have seen hundreds of records being queued in a TSD inside of a few seconds before, so what you are asking should be possible (just depends on the context and settings on your account).

Comment: I am using REST API : messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:<tsd_external_key>/send to send Emails...how many emails can 1 API call contain? I was aware that it can handles only 1 email per request at a time